# TTS for Android in RAW Folder

Tags: android, text-to-speech

Is it possible to directly install TTS (english) on my android application (raw folder) instead of depending on installing them on default system location (tablet) and then use them or is it automatically installed in the tablet and phones that way we don't need to worry in installing them again for Text to speech to work properly?

Let me know

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to do? Build a TTS engine or use one in your app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A TTS engine is a separate app and you cannot silently install it from your own app. You can only check if it is there and prompt the user to install it if it is not available.